# Best practice to store encryption keys/salt/password in Java

Tags: java, encryption

I have a configuration properties file that contains sensitive information, so naturally I want to encrypt them. I'm aware there are a lot of methods to encrypting them, but most of them requires a password/key/salt to encrypt and decrypt those values.

So my question is, what is the best practice to store those encryption keys? I don't have a database or server since the application that reads that config file does not need them.

Comment: Depends on the situation. What you are referring to is key management, and it really depends on a lot of things what is best. In Java, you'd generally store keys in key stores (preferably ones that are backed by the system).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes is that something stored in the code. Would it be possible to store them in a separate file?

Comment: Key stores *can* be files yes. JKS keystores or nowadays P12 (PKCS#12) files. They can be stored / loaded `KeyStore` and you can also manage them using `keytool`. There is also a default one that contains all the trusted certificates required for the JSSE implementation of SSL / TLS (but don't use that one, obviously).